# ASP.NET Http Modules Sequence - threading question

Tags: c#, asp.net, multithreading, httpmodule

We have multiple Http Modules in our ASP.NET application.
The modules are processing request and set some Thread Static variables.
However, sometimes it seems that the next Http Module in sequence is executed in a different thread than previous and the Thread Static variable is not set in such case.
Is there any way to guarantee that each Http Module will work in the same thread as previous.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, ThreadStatic should be avoided in an IIS context. Use HttpContext.Items instead. It is not possible to avoid the fact that IIS may serve a single request with multiple worker threads AFAIK. See, e.g. this [Scott Hanselman blog post](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ATaleOfTwoTechniquesTheThreadStaticAttributeAndSystemWebHttpContextCurrentItems.aspx)

Comment: Thanks. And what about sequence of modules? Can we rely that module that is declared in web.config first will be called first? By some reason MSDN misses this information.

Comment: I'm quite sure they've always been executed in the order declared in the config when I used them, but unfortunately I can't find any documentation that can back up that this is valid to rely on  and not just an artifact of how it is implemented in the current version of IIS.